# Crud method for query of enum list field in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have a user profile class that includes a field which is a list of enumerated roles:

```
enum UserRole {
    USER,
    ADMIN;

    public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 5;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "UserProfiles")
class UserProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    ...
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "UserRoles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @Column(name = "Role", length = UserRole.MAX_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<UserRole> roles;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, for readability user roles are stored as strings "USER" and "ADMIN" in the database. Note that a user may have multiple roles, i.e. both USER and ADMIN, hence the `roles` field is a list of enums.

In the user profile Crud, I tried to construct a query method that would return a list of either regular users or admins:

```
@Repository
public interface UserProfileCrud extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, Integer> {
    ...
    Iterable<UserProfile> findByRolesContains(UserRole userRole);
}
```

However, `findByRolesContains(UserRole.ADMIN)` fails with the following exception:

```
Parameter value [%ADMIN%] did not match expected type [domain.UserRole (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%ADMIN%] did not match expected type [domain.UserRole (n/a)]
```

Queries from the log:

```
Hibernate: select userprofil0_.id as id1_10_,
 userprofil0_.create_timestamp as create_t8_10_,
 userprofil0_.first_name as first_na9_10_,
 userprofil0_.last_login as last_lo11_10_,
 userprofil0_.last_name as last_na12_10_,
 userprofil0_.password as passwor13_10_,
 userprofil0_.role_names as role_na14_10_,
 userprofil0_.state as state15_10_,
 userprofil0_.update_timestamp as update_16_10_,
 userprofil0_.username as usernam17_10_
from user_profiles userprofil0_ where userprofil0_.username=?

Hibernate: select roles0_.id as id1_10_0_,
 roles0_.role as role2_11_0_
from user_roles roles0_ where roles0_.id=?
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [%ADMIN%] did not match expected type [domain.UserRole (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%ADMIN%] did not match expected type [domain.UserRole (n/a)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.findByRolesContains(Unknown Source)
    at repository.DatabaseUserProfileRepository.findAllAdmins(DatabaseUserProfileRepository.java:180)
    at repository.DatabaseUserProfileRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$284052c9.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654)
    at repository.DatabaseUserProfileRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43ea9293.findAllAdmins(<generated>)
    at admin.AdminController.adminMain(AdminController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%ADMIN%] did not match expected type [domain.UserRole (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 119 more
```

Is it possible to redefine the Crud method to work properly, without constructing an explicit SQL query in `@Query`?

Comment: Are you sure your `findByRolesContains`'s arg isn't `String`?

Comment: @AliDehghani `findByRolesContains(String userRoleName)` results in the same error when invoked as `findByRolesContains(UserRole.ADMIN.name())`.

Comment: I have the exact same config and it works

Comment: and are you going to share with us the actual JPQL invoked, and then the SQL invoked?, and perhaps the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Have you tried the same query without contains?

Comment: @AliDehghani I suspect that in your config you have a `String roles` field, so that is why `findByRolesContains(String userRoleName)` works for you.

Comment: @NeilStockton I added queries and stack trace as you requested.

Comment: @SimoneZandara Defining the method as `findByRoles(UserRole userRole)` results in a compilation warning: "Parameter type (UserRole) does not match domain class property definition (List)."

Comment: All: I think that the keyword Contains will not work in my config because it seems to apply to string fields not lists of enums -- check out how Containing (similar to Contains) is translated into SQL in Table 2.3 at [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html).

Comment: @NeilStockton I wrapped a call to `findByRolesContains(UserRole.ADMIN)` in a try/catch, printed the stack trace and updated the post. I do not know how to log the JPQL -- can you please let me know the appropriate setting in `application.properties`?

Comment: I'd assume the Hibernate log has it, or you find some Spring setting to show what the hell it is invoking. That's the problem with using libraries wrapping libraries ...

Comment: @NeilStockton I tried `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and `#logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and they both show the same queries that are in the post.

Comment: and I said **JPQL** ... not SQL (which you already posted).

Comment: @NeilStockton > I'd assume the Hibernate log has it...Hibernate knows nothing about JPQL, which belongs to JPA. There does not appear to be any facility to log JPQL. According to [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html), JPQL is a heavily-inspired-by subset of HQL, so even if you could log JPQL, you would not get much more info than what is already in the post.

Comment: Hibernate is a JPA implementation ... it USES the JPQL!! Oh well, don't provide the info so you're problem

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be defined as follows. I did not test it, so let me know if the outcome is correct.

```
@Repository
public interface UserProfileCrud extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, Integer> {
    ...
    Iterable<UserProfile> findByRolesIn(List<UserRole> userRoles);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine with `findByRolesIn(Collections.singletonList(UserRole.ADMIN))` (the resulting HQL has a "left outer join"). Adding `@ManyToMany` as you suggested results in the following: "Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: domain.UserProfile.roles[domain.UserRole]".

Comment: @user1408140 Your are right, that is because UserRole is not an Entity, so ElementCollection is appropriate as you already wrote. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I found out that it only works one way, i.e. to select ADMINs. If you try to invert the logic and use `findByRolesNotIn(Collections.singletonList(UserRole.ADMIN))` in hope of finding only non-ADMIN users, it still finds them because ADMINs also have the USER attribute. To overcome this, I had to change the approach: constructed a `@Transient boolean hasAdminRole` field that is computed upon `@PostLoad` from `roles.contains(UserRole.ADMIN)`. With this field, a Crud method `findByHasAdminRole(boolean value)` is feasible, and it also works with `Pageable`.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me (Spring Boot 5.0)

repo:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    List<User> findAllByRolesIn(Set<Role> role);
}
```

my pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr") // PostgreSQL not work with table "user"
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private boolean active;
    @NotNull
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

and Role.class:

```
public enum Role {
    ADMIN, MODERATOR, USER;
}
```